# How flutter calculates screen width

Tags: flutter

I have a simple flutter setup to get the width of the screen on device with resolution 2960*1440.

However, flutter returns a screen width of 411 when I run the application on resolution 2960*1440. How does flutter calculate width of a device?

```
class page extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString();

    return Container(
      child: Text("Height : $height and Width : $width"),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flutter depends on the `MediaQuery` method to calculate screen size :

```
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ;
```

as per the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/size.html)  it returns the number of the "logical pixels" of your screen which each one of them represent several physical pixels by a factor that differs from a device to another, and if you want the actual number of pixels you can use :

```
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio ;
```

and for the actual pixels of your screen height:

```
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio ;
```

Comment: For a good interpretation of this, check out this website: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions